# Is there a way to automatically change epic state to done when all the linked stories and tasks are complete

Tags: jira, kanban

I am new to JIRA and Kanban. I was expecting that when I create an epic and link some stories and tasks to it. The status of the epic will automatically change (e.g. to done) when all the stories and tasks linked to it are done. But it seems this is not the case. I can move the epic from the Backlog to the Done column even when its linked tasks and stories are still in the backlog. Is there a way to make JIRA prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been working on something similar. My intention was to set assigne of all linked issues of another one to a specific user when the status changes to a specific state.

I did this with a postfunction of the workflow of type: "Set Field Value to constant or Groovy expression"

In your situation I would do the following:

- go to "Close" transition, and click configure.
- select postfunctions, and add the type i told you.
- mark the chekbox that says execute only if condition is true
- set your condition. Probably something like issue.epic=your epic.
- Then you add your script, where you recover alll the issues linked to the epic, and check their status.
- Create your logic so that if everithing is as it should be, you just change the status, using MutableIssue object.
- remember that a field is going to be modified by this script, and i guess you cant choose status as field to be set. If this happens, choose summary, and store the current value, and use it to end your script, and set the summary value, whtih the same you had.
- Publish your workflow.

Excuse me if it is not clear, but is difficult to explain. Let me know if you need somenthing else.

PD: If you just want to do this at some specific moment and not for every epics automatically, just add Script Runner plugin, and run your script in the console. Much easier.

Regards

Comment: I will try what you said. I did not know we can write script in JIRA

Comment: Yes, i use groovy scripts. May be is needed the scriprunner plugin. I dont remember atm. Let us know

Comment: I can not find any part in the UI related to  "Close" transition or postfunction. Could you tell where I can find that, is it under board configuration or project  configuration? Sorry :) as I said I am new to  JIRA

Comment: Excuse me. I said the close transition refering to the last transition on a issue workflow. You should find something similar navigating to administration>issues>workflows>edit> here you choose the transition an then look for postfunctions

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it helps you:
I used jira with system language set to "Russian" (and i'm not good in groovy), that's why script below contains language dependencies (you should edit code if you use differ from my jira system language! At least change )

1. Use Scrip Runner plugin
2. Create "Custom listener" and paste code (code is not so good as can be but it's working):

   ```
   import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor;
   import com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueManager;
   import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue;
   import com.atlassian.jira.issue.link.IssueLinkManager;
   import com.atlassian.jira.issue.link.IssueLink;
   import com.atlassian.jira.issue.ModifiedValue;
   import com.atlassian.jira.issue.util.DefaultIssueChangeHolder;
   import com.atlassian.jira.issue.customfields.option.Options;
   import com.atlassian.jira.issue.customfields.option.Option;
   import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.config.FieldConfig;
   import com.atlassian.jira.issue.customfields.manager.OptionsManager;
   import com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager;

   ComponentManager componentManager = ComponentManager.getInstance();
   def groupMan = ComponentAccessor.getGroupManager()
   def authCon = ComponentAccessor.getJiraAuthenticationContext() 
   def customFieldManager = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager()
   def changeHolder = new DefaultIssueChangeHolder();
   IssueManager issueManager = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager();
   OptionsManager optionsManager = componentManager.getComponentInstanceOfType(OptionsManager.class);
   IssueLinkManager issueLinkManager = ComponentAccessor.getIssueLinkManager()

   def curUser = authCon.getUser()
   def issue = event.issue

   def epicLinkCf = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjects(issue).find {it.name == 'Epic Link'}
   if(!epicLinkCf) {log.warn "No Epic Link field"; return}
   log.warn "Existing Epic Link: ${epicLinkCf.getValue(issue)}"

   String epicIssue = epicLinkCf.getValue(issue)
   Issue epic = issueManager.getIssueObject(epicIssue) // epicKey is passed into your script

   // Check if Epic link is exist
   if(!epic)
       return true

   def newEpicState = "Сделано"

   log.warn "Epic: " + epic
   List<IssueLink> allOutIssueLink = issueLinkManager.getOutwardLinks(epic.getId());
   for (Iterator<IssueLink> outIterator = allOutIssueLink.iterator(); outIterator.hasNext();) {
       IssueLink issueLink = (IssueLink) outIterator.next();
       log.warn "child link type: " + issueLink.getIssueLinkType().getName()
       // Check status of all issues from epic
       if (issueLink.getIssueLinkType().getName() == "Epic-Story Link") {
           Issue chIssue = issueLink.getDestinationObject();
           log.warn "child state: " + chIssue.getStatusObject().getName()
           if(chIssue.getStatusObject().getName() == "В процессе") {
               newEpicState = "В процессе"
           } else if (chIssue.getStatusObject().getName() != "Закрыто" && newEpicState != "В процессе") {
               newEpicState = "Сделать"
           }
       }
   }

   def epicStatusCf = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjects(epic).find {it.name == 'Epic Status'}
   log.warn "Current epic status: " + epicStatusCf.getValue(epic)
   FieldConfig epicStatusFieldConfig = epicStatusCf.getRelevantConfig(epic);
   String oldStatus = epicStatusCf.getValue(epic)

   log.warn "New epic status: " + newEpicState
   // Set new status if it necessary
   if (oldStatus != newEpicState) {
       Options epicStatusOptions = optionsManager.getOptions(epicStatusFieldConfig);
       Option epicStatusDoneOption = epicStatusOptions.getOptionForValue(newEpicState, null);
       epicStatusCf.updateValue(null, epic, new ModifiedValue(epic.getCustomFieldValue(epicStatusCf),epicStatusDoneOption),changeHolder)
       log.warn "Epic status is updated!"
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Scriptrunner then you should be good to use the scriptrunner code. Please check this code from scriptrunner:

```
// Add the next line as a condition to the script listener, so it gets executed only for epic issues, the line must be written uncommented:
// issue.isEpic

// Check if the resolution has been changed
def resolutionChange = changelog.items.find {
    (it as Map).field == 'resolution'
} as Map
logger.info("The resolution change of issue '${issue.key}': ${resolutionChange}.")

if (!resolutionChange) {
    logger.info("The resolution didn't change.")
    return
}

// Compute the 'Epic Status' value to set based on the resolution value
def newEpicStatusValue = (resolutionChange.toString == 'Done') ? 'Done' : 'To Do'

// Get the 'Epic Status' field ID
final epicStatusField = get("/rest/api/2/field")
    .asObject(List)
    .body
    .find {
        (it as Map).name == 'Epic Status'
    } as Map
def epicStatusFieldId = epicStatusField.id

logger.info("Updating Epic Status field (${epicStatusFieldId}) to '${newEpicStatusValue}'.")
// Update the 'Epic Status' field value
put("/rest/api/2/issue/${issue.key}")
    .queryString("overrideScreenSecurity", Boolean.TRUE)
    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
    .body([
        fields: [
            (epicStatusFieldId): [value: newEpicStatusValue]
        ]
    ])
    .asString()
```

You can automate this code your post-function or automation in jira. Please find the further details in this [link](https://library.adaptavist.com/entity/change-epic-status-field-when-resolution-gets-set).

Answer (score 0):

*This question is from a few years ago and this answer relies on more recent options.*

You can use Jira Automations;
for example this one sets the Epic to "in progress" when work starts in one of the Epic issues or tasks.
https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Automation-for-Moving-Epics-to-In-Progress-Done-when-Any-All/qaq-p/1595808

Not what you asked, but you can adapt it to set the Status to Done instead.
This one might help: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/The-automation-rule-When-all-stories-are-completed-then-close/qaq-p/1842358