# How to automate transition of parent issue in Jira as soon as the Child issue changes status from "Pending" to "In Development"?

Tags: automation, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, jira-agile

Here I have a Parent Issues (Jira-1170) which **is developed by** a child issue (Jira-1589). 
Step 1:
My parent issue is in "Pending".
Child issue is created and it is in "Pending"
Step 2: 
Now developer worked on the request
so Child Issue is "In Development".

This transition in Child ticket must trigger the transition in Parent ticket automatically and set the status on parent ticket to "In Progress".

How can I do this? Please help me guys I am trying this for 5 weeks by watching different tutorials.

Thank You for Trying!!

Comment: You would probabaly need a Add-On for that. Bob Swift has a Update on Transistion that we use and it works well. You can get a trial in the Marketplace and see if it meets you needs.

Comment: If you like to expand the automation in your jira instance  try Adaptivst ScriptRunner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Jira Misc Workflow Extensions](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/292/jira-misc-workflow-extensions-jmwe?hosting=cloud&tab=overview) (JMWE) add-on to do this. What you need is a "[Transition parent issue](https://innovalog.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/JMWEC/pages/94142542/Transition+parent+issue)" post function to be added to the necessary steps in you workflow. This solution works for both Jira Cloud and Jira Server. However, the JMWE extension is not free.

In case you on Jira Cloud, you can use Automation add-on (it is built-in and free). Check out "Related issues condition" and the first of common use cases in this [guide](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/guides/expand-jira/automation#creating-a-rule).

Answer (score -1):

Hey maybe this thread helps you:
[Is there a way to automatically change epic state to done when all the linked stories and tasks are complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35468017/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-change-epic-state-to-done-when-all-the-linked-st)

Did you used Epics to structure your parent and subtasks or components?

Comment: That information would most probably be better supplied as a comment than an answer.  It does not actually answer the question and contains no info in the text of the answer except for a link to another answer.